# How to select all files, but exclude particular file extensions in a directory

Tags: regex, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-copy

I wanted to copy all files in a folder, but I wanted to exclude a particular file-extension in a sub-folder. How can I do that?

Here's a snippet of my code:

```
frontendDev: {
    files: [{
        expand: true,
        cwd: './frontend/app',
        src: ['!angular/*.js', '**/*.!(coffee|less|scss|sass)'],
        dest: './frontend/.dev'
    }]
},
```

**Note:** Here I wanted to copy all the files, but I wanted to exclude the (.js) files in the `angular` sub-folder.

Any thoughts? Thanks

## UPDATE - ANSWER

Base on what Raptis Dimos said **Inclusion and Exclusion order is important**.
So I put the inclusion first then last is the exclusion.

```
frontendDev: {
    files: [{
        expand: true,
        cwd: './frontend/app',
        src: ['**/*.!(coffee|less|scss|sass)', '!angular/**/*.js'],
        dest: './frontend/.dev'
    }]
},
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how it works. The ! in Grunt turns the expression into an "exclude" expression.

You can also check the [Grunt docs](http://gruntjs.com/api/grunt.file#grunt.file.expand), saying :

> Paths matching **patterns that begin with !** will be **excluded** from the returned array. Patterns are processed in order, so inclusion and exclusion order is significant.